# Join XMPP MUC with one JID simultaneously from different resources with openfire

Tags: xmpp, chat, openfire

I need to join in xmpp chat room with one jid but from different resources at same time.

It is not works. Server sends chat messages only to last joined device.

How do I configure jabber server (Open Fire) to allows room keep connection with same JID different resources?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9977661/is-it-possible-jids-with-only-different-resources-joining-same-multi-user-chat-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Openfire does not support multiple resources from the same JID in one MUC. See [OF-103](http://issues.igniterealtime.org/browse/OF-103)